# For x ∈ (0,1], prove that x < tan(x)

Tags: trigonometry

I was looking at a solution for some math problem regarding functions and in their solution they used that x < tan(x) for x ∈ (0,1] is true without giving proof for that. I was searching on other sites if someone had a similar problem as I have but couldn't find anything, so I am posting it here for someone else to help me.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Your proof will depend on the tools available.  The Taylor series makes it clear for $x \in (0,\frac\pi 2)$

Comment: You can use the convexity of $\tan$ or Taylor's formula

Comment: for a geometric proof look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881668/algebraic-proof-of-tan-xx